# Compose 3 UI element not updating with user input when value is previously provided

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have just recently started updating my app from the previous .xml to compose 3. One of the apps functions is for the user to be able to rate specific items out of 5 stars. The star rating is then saved in a shared preference key so if the user views the same item again, they can view their previous rating and change it if needed.

I noticed compose 3 doesn't have a built in ratingBar function, so I took some code I found online and modified it to work in the way I intended to, here is my method:

```
@Composable
fun RatingBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    rating: Float,
    prevRating: Float,
    stars: Int = 5,
    onItemClick: (Float) -> Unit
) {
    val displayedRating = prevRating

    Row(modifier = modifier) {
        (1..stars).forEach { starIndex ->
            val isSelected = starIndex <= displayedRating
            Image(
                painter = if (isSelected) painterResource(R.drawable.baseline_star_rate_24)
                else painterResource(R.drawable.baseline_star_outline_24),
                contentDescription = "",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        onItemClick(starIndex.toFloat())
                    }
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .size(30.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I pass through the values and display it like this:

```
                    var userRating by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
                    var previousRating by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
                    val previousR = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("generalRate${content}", null)
                    previousRating = previousR?.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f

                    ClickableRatingBar(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                        rating = userRating,
                        prevRating = if (previousRating != 0f) previousRating else userRating,
                        onItemClick = { clickedIndex ->
                            previousRating = clickedIndex
                            userRating = clickedIndex
                            println("User rated $userRating, $previousRating out of 5")
                        }
                    )
```

When there is no value for previous rating, it all works as intended, when you click a star, the U.I updates so that all the stars up to the point you clicked are full and ones after are empty. It also prints in the console with the correct X/5 value depending on where the user clicked.

My issue is when there is a previous rating. Say the user rated it 3/5 stars. 3 out of 5 stars would be filled in like intended. However when the user attempts to change the rating and interact with the ratingBar, it doesn't change. The printed value in the log is the correct value, displaying the right value depending on where the user clicked, but there is no change to the U.I and which stars are filled in/empty. I genuinely have no idea why.

Any and all help is appreciated! As said I'm new to compose so sorry if I'm using old logic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `RatingBar` composable `rating` argument is ignored and composable state is based on `prevRating` only. When `previousR` is `null`, `previousRating` is `0f`, and due to `if (previousRating != 0f) previousRating else userRating` statement `userRating` value is passed to the `RatingBar`. But when `previousR` is not `null` and `previousRating` have non-zero value then its value is passed to the composable instead of `userRating`. But `previousRating` will *always* have the same value because of the `previousRating = previousR?.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f`.

You don't need so many variables to hold the rating value, they should be replaced with a single source of truth. In this example the single source of truth is `userRating` backed by `MutableFloatState`. You will most likely have to hoist the state in a `ViewModel`. Read about state hoisting [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting).

```
var userRating by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(5f) }
RatingBar(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
    rating = userRating,
    onItemClick = { clickedIndex ->
        userRating = clickedIndex
        println("User rated $userRating")
    }
)
```

Another thing - you should put parameters without default values first. It will allow users to set them without using named parameters.

```
@Composable
fun RatingBar(
    rating: Float,
    onItemClick: (Float) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    stars: Int = 5,
) {
    Row(modifier = modifier) {
        (1..stars).forEach { starIndex ->
            val isSelected = starIndex <= rating
            Image(
                painter = if (isSelected) painterResource(R.drawable.baseline_star_rate_24)
                else painterResource(R.drawable.baseline_star_outline_24),
                contentDescription = "",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        onItemClick(starIndex.toFloat())
                    }
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .size(30.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise sates worked in that way. Cheers!